Can you return an SQL Query Resultset using Python Threading
I have two queries that take a while so I would like use threading to process them together.
AllPlayers = []
AllGames = []

conn.execute("EXEC SelectAllPlayers")
AllPlayers = conn.fetchall()

conn.execute("EXEC SelectAllGames")
AllGames = conn.fetchall()

I would like to run these two at the same time but I've looked at a couple of responses by people asking Threading questions and I just can't work it out.
I haven't tried anything yet.  I can see how threading works calling a function but returning a resultset ...

What makes you think that executing them in parallel will speed them up? SQL Server (if that's what you are using) already parallelizes queries, also you will probably run into disk IO problems first.

DB connections are usually not thread-safe, check the corresponding documentation of whatever API you are using, i haven't seen a single api that makes connection objects thread-safe, you need multiple connections at least

@Charlieface - Good question.  SQL Server already parallelizes queries which is great for SQL but it won't if it's been asked sequentially.   However, this was the most simplest of examples I could think of to ask someone to show me an example that returns a collection of values using threading.

No SQL Server can parallelize a single query (assuming you are not on Express Edition or LocalDB).
